# Do a case on the result of a subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, case

I was wondering how to do this in SQL.
From the **result** i get (**RESULT 2nd column**).
I want to check if this result is in the result of my **subquery** (**3rd column**) then set 'Y' or 'N' in the **SELECTED** (**4th column**)
for now, my SQL query looks like this :

```
Select ANALYTE as Value, RESULT
,(select DISTINCT CHARLIMITS from SPEC_ANALYTES where SPEC_ANALYTES.ANALYTE = @ANALYTE AND SPEC_ANALYTES.TESTCODE = @TESTCODE ) as subquery,
case when subquery then 'Y'
     else 'N'
End as SELECTED
from POSSIBLERESULTS
where   ANALYTE = @ANALYTE AND TESTCODE = @TESTCODE
```

What I have:

[image: What I have]

What I would like:

[image: What I would like]

I hope I made it understandable !
Thanks for taking the time to help me

Thibault.

Comment: corrected the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `LIKE` with wildcard matching in your case statement. In order to not repeat the subquery, I've used your current query as a sub query see below:

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    CASE
       WHEN subquery LIKE CONCAT('%',RESULT,'%') THEN 'Y'
       ELSE 'N'
    END as SELECTED
FROM (
    SELECT
        ANALYTE as Value, 
        RESULT,
        (select DISTINCT CHARLIMITS from SPEC_ANALYTES where SPEC_ANALYTES.ANALYTE = @ANALYTE AND SPEC_ANALYTES.TESTCODE = @TESTCODE ) as subquery,
   FROM 
       POSSIBLERESULTS
   WHERE 
       ANALYTE = @ANALYTE AND TESTCODE = @TESTCODE
) t
```